# C#, fill two Comboboxes with linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have two comboboxes, I want to fill them with a linq query from the SQL Server database, but just one combobox fills with data and another show nothing (exp: combobox1 =name+family of seller , combobox2=name+family of operator).

```
LittleEntity HamiCombo = new LittleEntity();
var HamiCombo2 = HamiCombo.Hamis.ToList();
var com2 = (from a in HamiCombo2 select new { HName = a.name + " " +      a.lname });
comboBox1.DataSource = com2.ToList();
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "HName";
comboBox1.ValueMember = "id";
LittleEntity PersonCombo = new LittleEntity();
var q = PersonCombo.People.Select(x => new { name = x.name + " " + x.lname }).ToList();
comboBox2.DataSource = q.ToList();
comboBox2.DisplayMember = "name";
comboBox2.ValueMember = "id";
```

Comment: is there actually data in PersonCombo.People or HamiCombo.Hamis?

Comment: Both of them, one of them for seller(name+family) and once for operator(name+family), I want each one to be displayed in a combobox.

Answer (score 1):

`HamiCombo2`, which fills your first `ComboBox` is being filled from the database.

`PersonCombo` is initialized to a `new LittleEntity()` which doesn't have any fields populated therefore there's no data to show in your second `ComboBox`.